# Запуск exe отдельно от родительского процесса

Tags: c++, winapi

```
CreateProcess("C:\\Windows\notepad.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, DETACHED_PROCESS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

Функция создаёт дочерний процесс как на рисунке[image: рисунок]

можно ли как то запустить notepad.exe отдельно от родительского процесса?

Comment: если кратко, в windows нет «дочерних» — «родительских» процессов как таковых... некоторые утилиты смотрят на аттрибут `InheritedFromUniqueProcessId`, но это ни на что не влияет, подробности: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947107/difference-between-creating-new-process-and-child-process-in-c-windows

Comment: @Abyx, из коробки в винде есть утилитка, с помощью которой можно это сделать?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону функции ShellExecute

Answer (score 2):

Флаг `DETACHED_PROCESS` означает лишь одно - что создаваемый процесс будет иметь отдельную консоль. Если процесс не консольный, он не будет иметь вообще никакого эффекта. Windows все равно пометит, что процесс был создан вашей программой. Утилиты, которые строят дерево процессов на основе информации, возвращаемой функциями [Tool Help API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/tool-help-functions) `Process32First`/`Process32Next` в поле `th32ParentProcessID` структуры [PROCESSENTRY32](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/ns-tlhelp32-tagprocessentry32) будут считать его дочерним. Если пользователь нажмет в диспетчере задач для вашей программы "Завершить дерево процессов", созданный процесс будет также завершен. С этим не надо бороться, это сделано специально, чтобы в ситуациях, когда программа из-за бага плодит много процессов без видимых окон и зависает, можно было решить проблему и завершить все эти процессы.

Тем не менее, создать полностью независимый процесс, который не завершается по нажатии "Завершить дерево процессов", возможно. Для этого можно использовать, например,  `system("start notepad.exe");`. Команда start запускает notepad и сразу возвращает управление, командный интерпретатор закрывается. Тогда в дереве процессов с точки зрения Windows родительским процессом notepad.exe будет уже не существующий процесс командного интерпретатора; соответственно, дерево разорвано и связи с вашей программой нет.

Comment: могу ли я поменять InheritedFromUniqueProcessId у процесса в PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION?

Comment: @ДмитрийМизантропович PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION не содержит такого поля. Видимо, вы имели в виду [TS_SYS_PROCESS_INFORMATION](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tsts/96702c7d-6f5f-4965-8f29-5fdbea73278e). Так как непонятно, в чем вообще назначение этой структуры, трудно сказать, можно ли поменять. У вас код для получения этой структуры есть?

Comment: NTSTATUS ntStatus = NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessBasicInformation, &procBasicInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION), &ulRetLength);

получит структуру PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION в ней есть поле InheritedFromUniqueProcessId

Comment: @ДмитрийМизантропович пробуйте это: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13950088/8674428